# Mathematical task - 10 balls in a bag

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So there is this mathematical problem that I cannot solve. I will be happy if someone explains me the way that this needs to be solved with good explanation. So:

There are 10 balls in a bag - 3 white balls, 5 red balls and 2 blue balls. A guy is picking them up without seeing their color (all the balls are drawn at random). How many different ways there are for the guy to pick them up? And second question -> In how many cases there arent drawn two balls in the same color one after other?

For the first question i have a guess in the solvation. So there are 10 balls. If there is one vector with the size = 10, each ball will go in one place of this vector.. 
a1, a2, a3, ... , a10..
For a1 there are maximum 3 choises -> red, white and blue.. but what is next?

I will be glad if someone explains me with details.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about balls in a bag.

Comment: Oh.. so i cannot post it in stackoverflow? I am new at this site and I will be happy if I dont spam unnecessarily.

Comment: This is more of a discrete mathematics question than a programming question, and as such would be off topic for Stackoverflow. A better option would be the Mathematics Stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you should know that Stack Overflow isn't really a site for discrete mathematics or similar areas. Try http://math.stackexchange.com. :)

But to answer your question:

You can draw 10 balls in 10! ways, right? However, you must exclude the numbers of same-color balls (because, obviously, drawing white ball no.1 and white ball no.2 is the same as drawing white ball no.2 and white ball no.1) - so, the number of ways is

10!/3!5!2!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the note. I am sorry for the wrong question in the site. I will keep in mind those tips when asking.

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions; instead vote-to-close.  Thanks.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, teaching somebody something is more important than your -1.

Comment: @Eutherpy: No, that just degrades the value of this site.  There are plenty of other sites for this kind of question, SO isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

For each permutation of ten (10!) there are 6 rearrangements of white balls,  120 rearrangements of red balls and 2 rearrangements of blue balls. So 10! has overcounted by 6x120x2 and the answer is just 10!/3!5!2!

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. I'm on multiple forums and I saw the discrete-mathematics tag without really thinking about it. I don't live on here so I don't know all the rules. I wondered if I should just go ahead and delete my answer after I realized. I'm starting to wonder why I waste my time only to lose more rep than I ever gain.

Comment: Its not from me, man. I only have 7 rep, and I need 15 in order to upvote/downvote. Thanks for your reply and @Oli Charlesworth is the guy, for whom teaching someone something is less important than having reputation. Thanks one more time for the fast answer and explaing it to me!